# Nested piping bash with mysql client

Tags: mysql, bash, pipe

In bash, I am trying to feed a "SHOW tables" query into mysql client and redirect the output into a *~/test* file, like this:

```
echo "show tables" | mysql | ~/test
```

The file remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

I verified that

```
echo "show tables" | mysql
```

does indeed produce the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect the output of a command to a file, use `>`, not `|`. Try this:

```
mysql -e 'show tables' > ~/test
```

I've used the `-e` switch to avoid needing to use `echo` with a pipe as well.

Comment: It works, thank you. Based on your answer, I could also do it this way:

`echo "show tables" | mysql > ~/test`